# Animations: jQuery vs CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, carousel

I've been building a custom jQuery "carousel" (slider) which continuously iterates over three images. So far that's working well, however I've had trouble trying to write code that changes the 'src' attribute of '#slideshow' while simultaneously triggering fadeIn or fadeOut.

My question: Am I tackling this properly (using jQuery) or should I resort to toggling a css animation instead?

Code:

```
$(function() {

    var slides = ['img/slide1.jpg', 'img/slide2.jpg', 'img/slide3.jpg'];

    function changeSlide(arr) {
      $('#slideshow').attr('src', arr[0]);
      var i = 1;
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#slideshow').attr('src', arr[i]);
        i++;
        if (i >= arr.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
      }, 3500);
    }
    changeSlide(slides);
});
```

For clarification my HTML for the carousel looks like such:

```
<div id="carousel">
  <img id="slideshow" src="img/slide1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#slideshow').attr('src', arr[0]);` add `fadeOut` before changing `src` and `fadeIn` after changing `src`.. Isn't it good?

Comment: Unfortunately that just loads the next image then fades it out to white.

Comment: Well you can use callback anonymous functions here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading all images initially to avoid requesting images continuously , substitute setting `class` to `slideshow` for `id` , utilize `complete` callback function of `.fadeIn()` , `.fadeOut()` on first image in parent element , next image in callback

```js
$(function() {
  function changeSlide(el) {
    $(el)
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(1500, function() {
        changeSlide(this.nextElementSibling || this.parentElement.firstElementChild)
      })
    })
  }
  changeSlide($(".slideshow:first"));
});
```

```css
.slideshow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="carousel">
  <img class="slideshow" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" />
  <img class="slideshow" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports" />
  <img class="slideshow" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works amazing, yes. I found another, similar way too. Now it's just a matter of crossfading the images instead of fading to white. Thanks!

Comment: @Jose _"Now it's just a matter of crossfading the images instead of fading to white."_ Try setting `css` `position` to `absolute` , adjusting `complete` callback at `.fadeOut()` to `start` function , e.g., `.fadeOut({duration:1500, start:function() {changeSlide(/*args*/)}})`

Comment: Thank you. Forgive me, I'm a little new. 
So when you say `/*args*/`, are you referring to `this.nextElementSibling || this.parentElement.firstElementChild`?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery in my opinion is far better option than using CSS. You are going good. Every code has some or the other bug which can be fixed later. You just have to be observant. That's all!

Comment: jQuery is really slow at animation.

Comment: But if someone has started it all then I think he should continue with that. Otherwise it will all get messed up.

Comment: Also see [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), a library that's (almost) a drop-in replacement for jQuery animation

Answer (score 0):

> I've had trouble trying to write code that changes the 'src' attribute of '#slideshow' while simultaneously triggering fadeIn or fadeOut.

If that's a way you want to do it, here's the way it *could* be done:

1) Preload all pictures to avoid src-change-triggered load.

2) Add `position:relative` to your #carousel, then add an additional `img` inside your slider.

3) Change `position` to `absolute` for both `img`s

4) Hide one 'img'

Alternate between images, so :

1 - you change the `src` of hidden one to "next" image

2 - you simultaneously fade out visible and fade in invisible one

3 - repeat